# Prevent expansion of \c in echo argument

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

I'm building a shell script with echo. I have something like:

```
echo "sed -i \"\\|charlie\.url\\s*=\\s*.*|c\\charlie.url = ${CHARLIE_URL}\" foo.conf" >> bar.sh
```

i.e. replace the line in **foo.conf** containing the current **charlie.url** (not necesarily at the begining, 'cause the line could be commented) for a new line with a new url.

I would expect the output to **bar.sh** to be

```
sed -i "\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c\charlie.url = ${CHARLIE_URL}" foo.conf
```

Nevertheless, the **`c\\charlie`** is interpreted as **`c` `\c` `harlie`**, instead of
**`c\` `charlie`**, which generates the following output:

```
sed -i "\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c
```

I have found that I could prevent this by using single instead of doubles quotes, but in that case `${CHARLIE_URL}` (which I do need to expand) does not get expanded.

How should my echo argument look like?

I'm using **dash** (#!/bin/sh under Ubuntu), but I could also use **bash** or **zsh**.

Comment: would help if we could see the actual data, along with the desired output/result

Comment: Note that `echo`'s behavior is extremely unreliable; it varies not just between shells, but between runtime configurations of each shell (f/e, in bash, set `xpg_echo` or `posix` flags, or have your environment variables set to enable them, and `echo` will suddenly do something different). Use `printf` instead -- as the POSIX standard for `echo` advises! -- if you want well-defined, consistent behavior. Stephane's excellent answer on [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) is well worth reading.

Comment: ...in particular, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, as backing for the above assertion that the POSIX standard for `echo` explicitly advises that `printf` be used instead. (The RATIONALE section, immediately below, describes how we got into such a situation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo`, you can try `cat` :

```
cat << EOF >> bar.sh
sed -i "\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c\charlie.url = ${CHARLIE_URL}" foo.conf
EOF
```

Comment: Pretty good breakdown of here-docs [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# bash will expand content within "" and stuff like $URL gets expanded
# also double-backslash reduces to a single; bash wouldn't expand stuff within ''

URL="https..."
echo double: "c\\charlie.url, URL $URL"
echo single: 'c\\charlie.url, URL $URL'

# if you need to output a \\
echo "\\\\"
```

Comment: This isn't reliably true, even with the interpreter known to be bash -- `echo` can perform an extra layer of backslash-escape sequence transformation, depending on the value of the `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags, which can be set by a parent process exporting the right environment variables, or at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The command line is using your first slash to quote your second one. If `CHARLIE_URL=foo`, your echo is actually outputting

```
sed -i "\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c\charlie.url = foo" foo.conf
```

Try using single quotes, but close/open them around the variable.

```
echo 'sed -i "\\|charlie\.url\\s*=\\s*.*|c\\charlie.url = '"${CHARLIE_URL}"'" foo.conf'
```

This produces

```
sed -i "\\|charlie\.url\\s*=\\s*.*|c\\charlie.url = foo" foo.conf
```

You could also, as mentioned, quote the slash that quotes the slash, and then quote the slash being quoted by the other slash, so that the subsequent iterations boil them down to what you want... but that's generally a mess, and leads to leaning-toothpick syndrome.

Someone made a good here-doc suggestion already, so I won't repeat that, but you can also use a "here string" which I generally prefer.

```
cat <<< "sed -i '\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c\charlie.url = ${CHARLIE_URL}' foo.conf"
```

I switched the double-quotes in your script for singles, assuming what you want is to output the literal value of $CHARLIE_URL into your script. If you want the script to use the variable, with whatever value is assigned at runtime, then quote that too -

```
cat <<< "sed -i '\|charlie\.url\s*=\s*.*|c\charlie.url = \${CHARLIE_URL}' foo.conf"
```